# How can I open up webcam and process images with docker and OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, docker, dockerfile

I have a python script that uses OpenCV and when somebody runs my script I want process the image from their webcam and give back a result. How can I make it?

This is how I tried:

My simple test python script:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    print ret
```

This is in my dockerfile:

```
FROM gaborvecsei/opencvinstall

ADD testcode.py ./testcode.py

#Start sample app
CMD ["python", "testcode.py"]
```

After I build this and I run it it always prints `False` so that means I do not have any image from the webcam.

How can I get the images?

Answer (score 0):

To make your cam visible from docker container, you should pass --device argument when start container.

```
docker start --device /dev/video0 helloworld:1.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to show the frame. Using `cv2.imshow('Preview', frame)`. And outside the `while loop` you have to release the camera, so you should type `cap.release()`.

Comment: I don't want to show the frame... On windows if I don't show it it prints always `True` so it's working

Comment: @GáborVecsei okay. So what do you mean by process the images from webcam and give back result ?!

Comment: Let's say, I get the image than threshold it and than return the contour areas.

Comment: @GáborVecsei so you mean how to do the processing, am I right?

Comment: No, I know how to process it. What I don't know is how to make this work with docker...

Comment: @GáborVecsei Unfortunately, I am not familiar with docker. But since the webcam returns `False`, try changing the argument `0` in `cv2.VideoCapture`. Try `1` or `-1` instead.

Comment: @GáborVecsei try changing the USB port on your PC with changing the argument in `cv2.VideoCapture()`. If you get nothing try changing the webcam itself. I am trying to give you all the possibilities. But I am sure that the webcam cannot be initialized that's why ret is always false. The problem is with the Python code, no need to add the docker code.

Comment: Thanks for the hints but I tried all that. I think I need something on my dockerfile